# Doing a php post to an api end point after a node is created or webform is submitted?

Tags: 7, rules

What modules are required to setup drupal to POST to an api endpoint when a node or a webform is created? I'd imagine it would be rules, but how would one set that up or is that even possible doing this via the interface without the need to code anything?

Answer (score 1):

There's already a built in HTTP client function [`drupal_http_request()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21common.inc/function/drupal_http_request/7.x) that's in Drupal core that can perform any HTTP verb, including POST.

As for what module, that's one of those broad, sorta DA off-topic, depends-on-your-use-case answers. Since you mentioned Rules, there's a [Rules HTTP Client](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules_http_client), that provides a Rules action wrapper around `drupal_http_request()`.

Also worth mentioning here, is the concern of adding an external web dependency within code responding node/webform submission; you're adding the possibility of locking up a node/webform submission request as PHP waits for a web response (e.g. if the API endpoint host is down). If you want to guarantee execution of an HTTP POST (and not hang your server), you should look at some sort of asynchronous solution (e.g. a queue job) if you can tolerate it.